# Which mode (sandbox or production) uses Apple during App Review?

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate, production

I have submitted my iOS app for the App Review. It uses Push Notifications, and I send push messages from my server. During development I used one type of APNS certificate, and sent to **tls://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195** address. On the production stage, the certificate and the address are different. Which ones should be set for the app review process - production or development mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use production certificates/provisioning profile for app review process.